# Restore DB in Full recovery model when there is no backup

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore, logfile, recoverymodel

Suppose I want to restore a database in such circumstances: from one side there is no backup,
from the other side - all the changes are stored in the log file.
Can I restore the database from the log file to a specific date & time?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about point in time recovery

for that you first need a full backup at least then if you take t-log backup you can restore. without full backup nothing possible